# Are there any specifics given as to how the Genosha mutant power suppression technology works?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, technology, mutant, powers

In the **X-Men** franchise, there are numerous human made tech which somehow stop mutants from utilizing their abilities.

It doesn't matter if the power is physical, psionic, or energy based; once applied, the tech effectively prevents them from being utilized, at least in the majority. This isn't the chemical from **X-3: The Last Stand** but actual devices of some kind. It was prominently seen in the 1990s **X-Men:The Animated Series**, [seen here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpTAJXV5_n0)

Such devices, as in actual collars, were also seen in [**Deadpool 2.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTpgIAwJO2E)

A variant of this, a psionic dampener, was used on Professor X in **X-2: X-Men United.**  However, that tool seemed more specifically designed to block *mental* powers, which conceivably could be done via some type of signal blocking or neural scrambler. Makes sense, considering Stryker's own son was a telepath, so he'd have time to develop tech [specific to that power type.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEK0vjwYgAU)

The basic premise is that the device *somehow* manages to "block the X-gene" without killing the mutant -  but this has some holes in it.

For instance, while that could work well with energy based powers, it *shouldn't* stop a mutant with muscle mass, higher contraction tissue and mitochondria levels from being super strong or durable, even *with* the collar on; by that point, it's less about their genes, and more about their physical structure.

So is there any more specific information about how this suppression technology actually works, in comics or in other media?